# Problema na exibição do JCalendar-1.4

Tags: java, data

Olá, tudo bem pessoal!
Estou criando uma programa e gostaria que ele tivesse um calendário na tela principal. Pesquisei e encontrei o jcalendar-1.4, porem, ao adicionar ele alguns números não são apresentados (ficam com três pontinhos). Alguém poderia me auxiliar na configuração?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está a imagem do componente quando o programa ainda não está em execução:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que são os componentes que tem o  `...`? São botões?

Comment: Math, boa tarde!
São numeros. Segue print i.imgur.com/s91cNP6.png
Obrigado

Comment: Pelo que entendi é o próprio calendar então depois de expandido (clicado para escolher a data), não é? A principio achei q o Calendar nao tava clicado e aquilo eram JButtons.

Comment: Na print (i.imgur.com/s91cNP6.png) o arquivo não esta sendo executado e o números aparecem corretamente...assim que executo ele fica os pontinhos.

Comment: Se você tirar o look and feel de Nimbus aparecem os números? Eu sei q não é uma resposta pedir para voce não usar o Nimbus, mas se puder fazer como teste.. Outra coisa, não da pra aumentar o tamanho do componente?

Comment: Math, redimensionei todo layout e ficou correto.
Obrigado pela ajuda e mau por não ter sido claro desde o inicio. Iniciante sabe como é :)
Obrigado, prosperidade e sucesso!
"Onde eu clico para pontuar você?"

Comment: Vou elaborar uma resposta para você :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que acontece é que quando você está desenvolvendo você tem uma prévia da sua tela, entretanto quando você roda seu programa o [Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) é aplicado e algumas propriedades dos componentes ficam bem diferentes, como por exemplo o `padding` pode aumentar e os números que tinham espaço de sobra para aparecerem agora ficam espremidos.

Para fazê-los aparecer basta aumentar o componente para ter certeza de que eles terão espaço suficiente para mostrar os números quando o programa estiver rodando.